# Regex long list of numbers

Tags: linux, regular-expression

What is the command in Linux to find the regular expression e for every number from 37 to 200 included in a list with such numbers?

Comment: Should that regexp match `64` and/or `44` in `foo644bar`? Should it match `1.44e2`, `0x36`, `0204`, `0060`, `+55`? Should that regexp extract numbers from text input or should it validate a string as a whole? Why are you asking for a regexp?

Comment: Indeed, the idea of using a regex to match a range of integers definitely rings warning bells that this is likely an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got a list of decimal integer numbers as sequences of 1 or more decimal digits, the first one not being `0` except for the number `0` itself, with no `+`/`-` sign, one per line, then you could use:

```
grep -xE '3[7-9]|[4-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|200'
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate these numbers and use them as a pattern list:

```
grep -xf <(printf "%s\n" {37..200})
```

So, for example

```
printf "%s\n" {1..1000..26} | grep -xf <(printf "%s\n" {37..200})
```

returns

```
53
79
105
131
157
183
```